# handle two different models for a dropdown

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I have two different models one is $scope.veh.vehCode and $scope.veh.vehName. after selecting vehicle Name from the dropdown need to send vehCode to the back end. During vehicle Update need to populate previously selected vehicle vehName but my  model $scope.veh.vehCode. how do I populate the vehName in dropDown?

for Update vehicle I al do getVehicles Rest call, In response i am getting vehicle Name that is VehName.

```
$scope.veh.vehCode = response.VehName

<label>Vehicle Name </label>
          <ui-select name="model" id = "model" ng-model="veh.vehCode"    ng-disabled="disabled" class="w-md mb-10">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a veh in the list...">{{$select.selected.model}}</ui-select-match>


              <small ng-bind-html="model.vehCode | highlight: $select.search"></small>
            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why you donnot use `ng-options`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-options` and `ui-select2` tag to handle this problem:

`vehic model:`

```
vehics = [{name: "name1", value: 1000},{name: "name2", value: 2000}]
```

`html code:`

```
<label class="control-label">vehic name</label>
<select ui-select2 style="width: 100%" name="vehicName" ng-model="vehicCode"
        ng-options="vehic.code as vehic.name for vehic in vehics"
        required>
    <option value="">--select vehic--</option>
</select>
```

By this code, **you see `vehic names` in your dropdown**, and when select an item, **your `ng-model` get `vehic code` value**.